# IIS site binding issues

Tags: iis

I have a site that I can run locally, but it's not accessible from my URL.

Here are the steps I've taken.

- I have an A record created to my external IP.
- My firewall has an access rule to allow the port I designated to be allowed in to the network from the WAN interface
- I have a NAT rule to send any traffic on that port to the IIS server running the site.
- I have disabled the Windows Firewall.

When I try and a get to the site via the URL + the port I get an error.  See the image below.

[image]

What have I missed??

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef You will have to use tools like Wireshark to assist troubleshooting and also follow the right order.

Comment: Is the site hosted on the Azure VM? If yes, check the port is open under the Networking section on the Azure Portal. Did you try to access the site using the default ports like 80 or 443? Are you using the HTTPS protocol with your site? Further, are you using any kind of proxy?